# can css be applied to controls of the page.aspx?

Tags: .net, css

Can css be applied to controls of the page.aspx?

To anything and everything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how  to use CSS elements in ASP.net application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030806/how-to-use-css-elements-in-asp-net-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and no.

You can't style server controls, as they never reach the browser, but you can style the HTML code that is rendered from the controls.

The server controls in the .aspx source only exist on the server while rendering the page. What's left of the controls when the page is sent to the browser is only the HTML code that the controls are rendered as. For example, a `TextBox` control renders as an `input` or `textarea` element.

You can use CSS to style the elements that the controls render, but for that you need something to target the element. You can for example specify a `CssClass` value for a control which will be rendered as a `class` attribute in the HTML code. Another alternative is to specify a class or an id on the surrounding element.

The `ID` of a server control is however not useful for targeting the elements in CSS. Whenever a control is within a container (like a `PlaceHolder` or `Repeater`), it's identity is prepended with the container name to keep identities unique.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider [Themes and Skins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx) for asp.net.

Otherwise use the `CssClass` property on the control.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="CSS_class_here" runat="server" Text="Click me" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give each element a CSS class name, then yes.