# asp:Menu not formatting correctly when run from server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net-4.0

In the Site.Master page that came with VS 2010, there is a menu that is supposed to be displayed horizontally. It looks when I run in debug mode from VS, but when its on the server, the tabs or displayed vertically. Here is the asp code:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="true" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <%--<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Home.aspx" Text="Home"/>--%>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Loan.aspx" Text="Loan Device"/>
                    <%--<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Return.aspx" Text="Return Device"/>--%>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/InternationalSwap.aspx" Text="International Swap" />
                    <%--<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/InventoryControl.aspx" Text="Inventory Control" />--%>
                    <%--<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Reports.aspx" Text="Reports" />--%>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Administration/InventoryControl.aspx" Text="Administration" />
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
```

At the bottom of the page is a little javascript that causes an error in IE,

```
<script type='text/javascript'>new Sys.WebForms.Menu({ element: 'NavigationMenu', disappearAfter: 500, orientation: 'horizontal', tabIndex: 0, disabled: false });</script>
```

But when i run it locally from VS, there is no error. Could there be something that is missing from the server that my local machine has?

Comment: Is it possible that your server doesn't support asp.net 4.0? You might also want to check out this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063156/asp-net-4-0-rendering-problems-with-the-menu-control-after-removing-of-controlre).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue while I'm using Routing and I fixed it by changing the **URL pattern** for the route.

Also if there is no need to use Global.asax in your project try to remove it.